# How can I prevent link behavior on clicking an image inside an anchor element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code similar to this:

```
<a href='link.html'>goto link page <img src='images/edit.gif' alt='Dont Go, just edit' onclick='doEdit()'></a>
```

Now I want the href link to work as normal if you click on the text, but if you click on the image, it should do something else and not goto the link at all.

There is also a restriction, I cannot edit the link or its text, the only thing that I have total control over is the img tag and its called onclick function. So I have to prevent the link from going on from within that img tag.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want the href link to work as normal if you click on the text, but if you click on the image, it should do something else and not goto the link at all.

The correct way to do that is to not put the `img` inside the link.

However, if you really want to do that, change your onclick to:

```
onclick='doEdit(event)'
```

...and in `doEdit`:

```
function doEdit(event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();    // Standard
    }
    else {
        event.cancelBubble = true;  // Old IE
    }

    // ...your img logic...
}
```

That will prevent the `click` event from bubbling to the link. You need the test for `stopPropagation` because IE8 and earlier don't have it (or `preventDefault`), they use properties instead (`cancelBubble = true` for `stopPropagation` and `returnValue = false` for `preventDefault`). (We're probably stuck with IE8 at least another year, maybe more, despite XP end-of-life...)

Comment: oops I got so many correct answers and only one could be accepted... but I guess your answer is perfect... although it appeared a little late

Comment: @mim: I had `false` where I should have had `true` in there, fixed now. Also added note about why one does the check.

Answer (score 3):

Just `preventDefault` on the *click event* when the *target* is an `<img>`

```
yourAnchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG')
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Ok, good idea, let me check if I can use the parent reference of this img tag to prevent this, because as I said, I have no control over the parent href tag

Comment: thanks a lot, your answer helped me make it work, I passed event object like this `<a href='link.html'>goto link page <img src='images/edit.gif' alt='Dont Go, just edit' onclick='doEdit(event)'></a>` and then used e.preventDefault() from within the function doEdit(e){}... thanks again... im waiting for it to allow me to accept the answer

Comment: thank you again... you gave me the idea to fix it.. but @T.J. Crowder posted the exact solution

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `event` through to the doEvent method call, similar to this:

```
<a href='link.html'>goto link page <img src='images/edit.gif' alt='Dont Go, just edit' onclick='doEdit(event)'></a>
```

Then you can call `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the event and do your own thing, similar to this:

```
function doEdit(event){
    // your code here

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mMYDU/) - Using the event object to cancel the event.

---

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is to simply remove the image tag from between the link tags.

```
    <a href='link.html'>goto link page</a>

    <img src='images/edit.gif' alt='Dont Go, just edit' onclick='doEdit()'/>
```

Are there more restrictions that do not allow you to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you mean but if you want the text to have a link and the image to have a onclick event

text

```
<a href='link.html'>goto link page</a>
```

image

```
 <img src='images/edit.gif' alt='Dont Go, just edit' onclick='doEdit()'></img>
```

Comment: That is not the way to close an image tag, they are essentially self-closing.

Comment: ahh sorry didn't know that I was just guessing it was still a open div tag